# iFrame or a remote JS File

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I've got a complex page that can be customized and should be embedded in some clients' websites. For each client it should look the same, but the parameters can be little different. The page also contains a custom object that uses a plugin in the browser.

I had 2 idea to accomplish this:

1. Using an iFrame - so I just embed my page and pass parameters in the
   querystring.
2. Using a remote JS file - like Facebook SDK and others
       work. Passing parameters in the JS code. As I understand, I can just put some 'parent' div on the page and the remote JS file, which should fill the parent div with the needed elements.

Which one should I use? What are the cons / pros of each one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38701/Developing-Widgets-with-ASP-NET-WCF-and-jQuery) which has an in depth look into the ways of what you're trying to achieve.

Pros of IFrame:

> If the owner of the mashup page is really concerned with security, malicious scripts running in the widget, then the IFRAME approach is preferable, because the widget’s script will have limited access to the host page and hence couldn’t make much harm to the page where it's embedded into.
>
> Also, this approach is preferable if the owner of the widget wants to control the layout and styling of his/her widget. Since the IFRAME is essentially a separate web page, the mashup’s CSS scripts can’t do much harm to the widget.

Cons:

> it is slow, resource intensive [on the browser], and does not give the owner of the mashup page an ability to style the widgets the way s/he wants.

Comment: @Kamyar What about the pros and cons of the js file approach?

Comment: take a look at `Embedded Widget: Background, Pros and Cons` in that article.

Comment: Also, I have learned a lot from http://blog.errorception.com/2012/01/writing-quality-third-party-js-part-1.html  It's a 3-part explanation of providing third party js widgets.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issue some time ago. You bassicaly have three options to choose depending how secure and flexible your plugin should be.

### iframe

**pros**

- fairly secure - you can present data that should be viewed to specyfic user only and allow passing sensitive data to your service. Page that includes your plugin will not have access to it.
- page that includes your iframe will not be able to modify it's content to confuse user

**cons**

- slow
- limited communication between your plugin and the page(may be solved by between-window post message/porthole, but this is not perfect)
- page still may scam users into beliving they see your plugin, while present own copy or use click jacking
- if you include any assets from 3-rd party server that bit of security you had is lost
- limited to rectengular box

### script

**pros**

- extremly flexible
- easy to implement variety of callbacks to react on events on the page
- fast
- may integrate with interface of the page in many different ways and spots

**cons**

- basically can be modfited in any possible way by page that includes it. You have no controll what users will see in the end.

### redirect through your service and then back

**pros**

- most safe solution

**cons**

- hardest to seamlessly integrate
- may not interact with other elements of website that uses plugin(since when users see your plugin they are't seeing source website anymore)

Comment: Thank you for the great review. I would add at the 'script' that one of the cons is a more cumbersome include. With an iFrame you can use just one line of code, using the script approach - you will need a container and a script at the bare minimum, probably more parameters coming too.

Comment: Acually you can construct container by `createElement` function. For e.g. directly above `script` tag to let know developer where it will land.